# how to make edit with combobox codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

[image: this my problem if i choose status Tidak Aktif another status cant display and show this error or otherwise]

I have a problem with update combobox, it's showing data from the database but I can't change data.

I have some statuses, status 1 for aktif and status 2 for Tidak Aktif

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label lbl">Status Data : </label>
          <br>
           <select name="STATUS" id="STATUS">
            <?php if ($key['STATUS'] == 1 ){$Aktif="selected=selected";}
              if ($key['STATUS'] == 2 ){$Tidak_Aktif="selected=selected";}?>
            <option value="1" <?=$Aktif?>> Status Aktif </option>
            <option value="2" <?=$Tidak_Aktif?>> Status Tidak aktif </option>
                </select>
                </div>  
        </div>`
```

Comment: Your requirement is not clear.  What exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: I had my fix and add pictures

Comment: Please be clear with your question. Do you want to update your combo box entry in DB or what ?

Comment: If so, then please show your code for update query.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ternary operator(?:)` for checking status:like this..

```
<?php 
$Aktif = ($key['STATUS'] == 1)?"selected":"";
$Tidak_Aktif = ($key['STATUS'] == 2)?"selected":"";
?>
<select name="STATUS" id="STATUS">
    <option value="1" <?php echo $Aktif;?> > Status Aktif </option>
    <option value="2" <?php echo $Tidak_Aktif;?> > Status Tidak aktif </option>
</select>
```

After submitting form get value like this..

```
$status = $this->input->post('STATUS');
```